# Using trust manager for accepting self signed certificates in java

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I would like to know how to use trust manager to accept a self signed certificate in java. I was able to avoid common name check using the following code:

```
HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(port).getConduit();
TLSClientParameters tlsCP = new TLSClientParameters();
tlsCP.setDisableCNCheck(true);
HttpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsCP);
```

But I would prefer using trust manager instead.

Comment: Is this CXF? If so, does http://stackoverflow.com/a/7918512/504685 apply?

Comment: yes this is CXF. I checked the link you provided. Are you sure using a dummy trust manager is the way to bypass a self signed certificate ?

Comment: When you say 'bypass' do you really mean 'accept'?

Comment: yes i want to accept.

Comment: alright. my mistake. so how do i do it ?