# Does REST (RestTemplate) in Spring Library support HTTPS protocol?

Tags: java, spring, rest, https

I'm trying to connect to a web server via `HTTPS`, but `response.getBody()` returns `null` however I want to return a JSON array. The `statusCode` is 200 and the headers contain the correct information, but the response body is `null`. I'm using the standard Spring `RestTemplate` API for this purpose specifically `postForEntity()`. Maybe in order to do this I have to use some special Spring API?

Unfortunately I couldn't find any information about `HTTPS` support and `SSL`/'TLS' certificates in the Spring REST documentation (it is quite limited).

Comment: What does "can't get any response" exactly mean? Any error code?

Comment: Okay, and what's the status code of the response? If it is "200" the request itself should be okay. Can you verify on the server side that the request how you send it generally works? For instance try to call the url your application calls with your webbrowser.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can configure the `RestTemplate` with the `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`, for example:

```
<bean id="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"/>

<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"/>
</bean>
```

That allows the `RestTemplate` to use the [Apache HttpComponents HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/) under the hood, which definitely supports SSL.

It looks like the `HttpClient` provided by `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` supports SSL out of the box, so there may be almost no configuration required on your side.

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov You can add it to the Application Context or you can create the objects programatically, e.g. new RestTemplate(...) I just used an xml example as that's generally typical. Unfortunately I cannot comment on Android, I don't have much experience there. :-)

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov I wasn't aware of this change, I've updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov No problem, glad I could help in some way.

Comment: @Jonathan, how can i implement this factory through **new RestTemplate(...)**? What should i put inside *RestTemplate()*?

Comment: @Alexandre The equivalent in Java would be: `new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory())`. If you need further assistance, I recommend you ask it as new question - you'd at least get more timely responses. :-)

Comment: I'm aware I'm commenting on an older post here, but I think you may need to update the constructor-arg ref to use the changed bean name.  Otherwise +1; it helped me! :)

Comment: Also, you must add httpclient to your dependencies, if you are using maven, as this is not automatic in any way...