# RestTemplate with x509 certificate

Tags: java, spring, https, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have to use secured endpoint which forces to use https access, authors of this endpoint provided me with x509 cetrificate file which, as I understand, I should use when making requests to the endpoint. I've been looking for some examples of using RestTemplate with x509 .crt file as I use Spring Boot and was unable to find it. Is that possible or should I uses another http client (not Spring RestTemplate),

Thanks,

Andrey

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955409/does-rest-resttemplate-in-spring-library-support-https-protocol